# Not able to understand meteor specific syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I was reading about Meteor publishing and subscription, where i came across a small code snippet. Although, i understood the concept of the article but could not understand the code syntax of snippet. Please help me?

```
Meteor.publish('lists.public', function() {
  return Lists.find({
    userId: {$exists: false}
  }, {
    fields: Lists.publicFields
  });
});
```

Comment: Which part exactly is unclear?

Comment: the part inside find method

Comment: I don't see a meteor specific code per se. He's doing a normal find then he's white listing what fields he'd like to return back. Please refer back to the aforementioned article you'd find that he's setting  `Lists.publicFields` to a certain object.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Comment: The code you are referring to is in fact Mongo code, not Meteor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code annotated with explanations. Does this help?

```js
// publish the result of this function to the client under the name 'lists.public'
Meteor.publish('lists.public', function() {  

  // Find in the Lists collection..
  return Lists.find({
    // ..all documents there the field userId does *not* exist.
    userId: {$exists: false}
  }, {
    // From the found records, only return the fields listed in Lists.publicFields.
    fields: Lists.publicFields
  });
});
```

You may also want to `console.log(Lists.publicFields)` somewhere in case you are not sure what's in there. This is not meteor specific and I cannot tell what is set in there. Might be done by a package you are using.